# Component Equivalent to OR in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a very very long db2 query in which there are many sections each particular to a territory. Trying to run this query in SQL or SSIS is resulting in an error because of its length. Each section is split by an OR. I am planning to split these sections and put into different sources in ETL and then join them. I need to know if there is any component that works exactly as the or function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Geethanjali

Comment: What do you mean "very long"? If it's that long, why don't you replace it with a VIEW? What does this query do?  Besides, SSIS isn't a query generator. The Join component doesn't create a JOIN statement automagically, it joins two data sets already in memory. Query problems should be addressed by fixing the *query*. The typicall pattern is to load any relevant data into staging tables, not perform a complex operations on the source database

Answer (score 1):

Separate each of your *OR* into a single query each. Then use a UNION ALL transformation.

Now use the below approach to remove the duplicates.
http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/09/ssis-how-to-perform-union-operation-in.html